# How add text without new line in QTextEdit PyQt4 Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4, qtextedit

I have problem with add text without new line in QTextEdit. 
I must add the value of variable "self.value" and next text ",   word"
It's my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Text(QWidget):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(Text, self).__init__(parent)

      self.value = 5

      layout = QHBoxLayout()
      self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
      self.text_edit.append(str(self.value))
      self.text_edit.append(",   word")
      layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)
      self.setLayout(layout)
      self.setWindowTitle("TextEdit")

def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = Text()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

And I get:

```
5
,   word
```

But I would like:

```
5,   word
```

Help me, please

Comment: Move the cursor to the end of the document and then insert the text.

Answer (score 2):

Easily like this

```
  self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
  self.text_edit.insertPlainText(str(self.value))
  self.text_edit.insertPlainText(",   word")
```